# Python MSAL - admin consent required error, when consent is already given

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to request the `Directory.Read.All` scope using Microsoft's MSAL library & retrieve a valid access/refresh token pair with the `acquire_token_by_authorization_code` function.

I ask an organization's admin to consent to the above application permission with the `/adminconsent` endpoint (and have confirmed that permissions have been granted - see screenshot below). However, when trying to retrieve an access token with the `Directory.Read.All` scope, I get the following error:

```
{'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': "AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'XXX' named 'XXX'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource [...]'suberror': 'consent_required'}
```

Not exactly sure how this can be the case - as the permission is clearly granted. I have tried resetting the token cache by removing all MSAL accounts, but doubt this is the root of the issue, as the actual step that fails is converting an authorization code to access token.

Thanks for any help!

[image: Microsoft AD page for permissions]

Comment: Please share the MS graph request you are trying to achieve

Comment: Hi,@dannybess, Can you get an authorization code?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Very thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your error:

[image]

If you use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to obtain an access token, you should grant delegated permissions, because this is a authorization flow with user interaction, so try to grant **Directory.Read.All** `delegated permissions`, and then grant **admin consent** for the permissions.

[image]